# Make RSS feed only accesible by Mailchimp

Tags: customization

I'm developing a private site for a customer (only accesible by loggin in) and I would like to make the RSS feed only accesible by MailChimp.

I know how to take the feed out of the auth_redirect and is_user_logged_in function, but I don't know how to make that specific URL only accesible by MailChimp (if there's a way)

Comment: What about creating a new feed with a "secret" slug and give that to MailChimp ?

Comment: It's a possibility, but it would be open to everyone else as well. If there is no way to limit the access to mailchimp, I will sure use your idea!!

Comment: Going more specific than that would require details on MailChimp setup/fetching API. For example if MailChimp supports http authorization or other kind of auth with e.g. rest api, xml-rpc etc.

Comment: They just fetch the data via RSS, that's why I thought that limiting the access to /feed/ from certain URL would be enough. But I just can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: *use a public RSS feed with MailChimp.* says [here](https://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/blog-posts-in-campaigns/troubleshooting-rss-in-campaigns) in the MailChimp's KB.

Comment: I know, and that's why I'm asking if there is a way to make a public page only visible to certain URL, so that way I can make Mailchimp read that feed, because it would be public to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, the solution has been, as [birgire](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/26350/birgire) pointed out, creating a custom feed and only allowing access to that URL:

```
// Create new feed
add_action('init', 'customRSS');
function customRSS(){
    add_feed('supersecretfeed', 'customRSSFunc');
}

function customRSSFunc(){
    get_template_part('rss', 'supersecretfeed');
}
```

Then, as the site is private, I had to allow public access to that specific URL, adding the is_feed option:

```
// Ban non logged users
function protect_whole_site() {
    if(! is_page( 'wp-login.php' ) && ! is_feed('supersecretfeed') && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        auth_redirect(); 
    }
}
```